# Dispatched action with Redux not working, getting uncaught typeError, saying it's not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a very simple action being dispatched, basically to make sure everything is working fine. Unfortunately I keep getting:

`Uncaught TypeError: _this2.props.testFunction is not a function`

I've checked everything and it all seems fine. Here is my code:

```
//index.js
const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();
const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, loggerMiddleware);

const store = createStore(allReducers, middleware);

export default class Help2 extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <App/>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

//reducers/index.js
const allReducers = combineReducers({
    topic: TopicsReducer
});

export default allReducers;

//reducer/test-reducers.js
export default function(state=null, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case 'TEST_REDUCER':
            return action.payload; //will return that object
            break;
    }
    return state;
}

//actions.js
export function testFunction(topicsUrl){
    console.log('I have been called');
     const request= axios.get(topicsUrl);
     return (dispatch)=>{
         request.then(({data})=>{
             dispatch({type: 'TEST_REDUCER', payload: data,});
         });
     }

};

//container/test.js
export class Test extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
                <div onClick={()=>this.props.testFunction("https://api.someApi.com/")}>Click here to test</div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
        topic: state.topic
    }
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({testFunction: testFunction}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(Test);
```

Soo, anyone have a clue what could be going wrong?

Edit: fixed the action type

Edit2: Here is the stuff I am importing in container/test.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {testFunction} from '../actions/actions';
```

Comment: Right above where you call `matchDispatchToProps` can you console.log(testFunction) and make sure its actually a function. Have a feeling it might not being imported properly but wouldn't know since can't see the entire file structure for test.js

Comment: @finalfreq I have actually done that, and console.log is not being called. I have also tested the action being called by itself, which is working fine. So the problem is definately at matChDispatchToProps or the connect. I will add an edit with my imported stuff for container/test.js for you to see.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

I was using export default for connect and exporting my component. While importing just the component.

I can't believe I did that!